# OSX -- python is hashed (/urs/local/cellar/python/2.7/etc)

Tags: python, bash, macos, hash

As I was fiddling some bash scripting on osx, I seemed to have done irreparable damage to my python installation.
Long story short, I typed `hash python` in the terminal and now I can't use python.
Lets say I try:

`python code_to_run.py`

I get:

`python is hashed (/path/to/my/python)`

I've tried `hash -r` and `hash -d python` to no avail.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Try `unhash python`

Comment: unhash is not a bash command (first thing I tried)

Comment: what does `type python` say?

Comment: python is hashed (/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python)

Comment: Try closing (quitting) terminal and reopening it (relaunching).

Comment: I've closed/reopened/restarted several times.

Comment: and typing `python` into your terminal gives you `python is hashed (/path/to/my/python)`?

Comment: after a restart, `type python` returns `python is /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python` but typing `python` after that returns `python is hashed (/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python)`

Comment: interestingly, typing `hash` says hash table is clear yet python still says it is hashed.